# How do I search for a specific email domain in a text data in R?

Tags: regex, r, email-validation

I have a text dataset, that I want to loop through to find out if a specific email domains are there.

```
sample_emails = c("xyz@harvard.edu","xyz@gmail.com","zyx@harvard.edu")

sample_match = unlist(regmatches(sample_emails, gregexpr("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@harvard.edu$",sample_emails)))
```

What I expect to get is a list with "xyz@harvard.edu" and "zyx@harvard.edu".

Instead, I get this:

```
> sample_match
character(0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just `grep("harvard.edu", sample_emails, fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE)`

Comment: @RichardScriven what to do about the `@` symbol? probably not an issue but could have `"harvard.edu@yale.edu"`

Comment: I suppose we could throw an `@` at the front then

Comment: @RichardScriven cool. i guess you don't need to escape it because `fixed=T`?

Comment: Right.  No escapes needed when we use `fixed`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 sample_emails[grep('.*\\.edu',sample_emails)]
    [1] "xyz@harvard.edu" "zyx@harvard.edu"
```